# Dialog box does not work for SAP Business One Add-On

Tags: c#, sapb1

I have used the code below for my SAP Business One add-on that reads Excel sheets from a dialog box. While testing my addon, I placed a breakpoint at

```
Thread.Sleep(1);  // Wait a sec more
```

in Visual Studio 2012. This enables the dialog box to open so that I can select the Excel file because in SAP

1. The dialog must be run on a separate thread.
2. The dialog must be modal for the correct instance of the SAP client window.

While debugging/testing in Visual Studio, the addon runs fine and can select an Excel sheet which copies to a matrix.
However, when I make an .ard with .exe file to register in SAP (an executable file), the addon hangs soon after I choose an excel file (press OK) on the dialog box.

What am I doing wrong in the code?#

```
private void GetFileHeader()
        {
            using (GetFileNameClass oGetFileName = new GetFileNameClass())
            {
                oGetFileName.Filter = "Excel files (*.csv)|*.csv";
                oGetFileName.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                Thread threadGetExcelFile = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oGetFileName.GetFileName));
                threadGetExcelFile.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

                try
                {
                    threadGetExcelFile.Start();
                    while (!threadGetExcelFile.IsAlive) ; // Wait for thread to get started
                    Thread.Sleep(1); // Wait a sec more
                    threadGetExcelFile.Join(); // Wait for thread to end

                    var fileName = string.Empty;
                    fileName = oGetFileName.FileName;

                    if (fileName != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string connString = "";
                        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                        // Initialize connection string
                        connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"", fileName);

                        // Connect
                        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);

                        // Open connection if closed
                        if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                            myConnection.Open();

                        string fName = fileName;

                        fName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fName);

                        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + fName + "$] WHERE RecordKey IS NOT NULL";

                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                        adapter.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt != null)
                        {
```

The GetFileNameClass

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SBOPlugins.Enumerations
{
    public enum eFileDialog { en_OpenFile = 0, en_SaveFile = 1 };
}

namespace CoreFrieght_Intraspeed
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper for OpenFileDialog
    /// </summary>
    public class GetFileNameClass : IDisposable
    {
        #region The class implements FileDialog for open in front of B1 window

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog _oFileDialog;

        // Properties
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _oFileDialog.FileName; }
            set { _oFileDialog.FileName = value; }
        }

        public string[] FileNames
        {
            get { return _oFileDialog.FileNames; }
        }

        public string Filter
        {
            get { return _oFileDialog.Filter; }
            set { _oFileDialog.Filter = value; }
        }

        public string InitialDirectory
        {
            get { return _oFileDialog.InitialDirectory; }
            set { _oFileDialog.InitialDirectory = value; }
        }

        //// Constructor
        //public GetFileNameClass()
        //{
        //    _oFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //}

        // Constructor
        public GetFileNameClass(SBOPlugins.Enumerations.eFileDialog dlg)
        {
            switch ((int)dlg)
            {
                case 0: _oFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog(); break;
                case 1: _oFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog(); break;
                default: throw new ApplicationException("GetFileNameClass Incorrect Parameter");
            }
        }

        public GetFileNameClass()
            : this(SBOPlugins.Enumerations.eFileDialog.en_OpenFile)
        {

        }

        // Dispose
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _oFileDialog.Dispose();
        }

        // Methods

        public void GetFileName()
        {
            IntPtr ptr = GetForegroundWindow();

            WindowWrapper oWindow = new WindowWrapper(ptr);

            if (_oFileDialog.ShowDialog(oWindow) != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                _oFileDialog.FileName = string.Empty;            
            }
            oWindow = null;
        } // End of GetFileName

        #endregion

        #region WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window

        public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
        {
            private IntPtr _hwnd;

            // Property
            public virtual IntPtr Handle
            {
                get { return _hwnd; }
            }

            // Constructor
            public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
            {
                _hwnd = handle;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is to not to create a new thread, but instead, in the method `GetFileHeader()`, call `oGetFileName.GetFileName()` directly.

The new thread is not needed because it seems that the intent is that the application should wait until the file is chosen anyway.

Hope this helps
Fredrik

Comment: I tried doing away with the thread and calling oGetFileName directly. I made and .ard file and executable. When I run the program now, nothing happens when I click on the button to open dialog. I believe that for SAP, the dialog must be run on a separate thread.